# How to convert <null> to null of dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary, null, nullable

How to convert params of dictionary `<null>` to `null`

```
var params = [String: Any]()
    params["name"] = nameValue?.count ?? 0 > 0 ? nameValue : NSNull()
    params["id"] = idValue?.count ?? 0 > 0 ? idValue : NSNull()
    params["time"] = timeValue?.count ?? 0 > 0 ? timeValue : NSNull()
```

Above code is constructed the params.

```
Before
     ▿ 0 : 2 elements
        - key : “name”
        - value : <null>
     ▿ 1 : 2 elements
        - key : “id”
        - value : <null>
     ▿ 2 : 2 elements
        - key : “time”
        - value : <null>
```

After

```
name: null
id: null
time: null
```

Comment: Swift doesn't know `null`, did you mean `nil`?

Comment: `var params = [String: Any?]()`?

Comment: @koen I have to construct params for api call {"name":null,"id":null,"time":null} error message show differently if not structed in this formate.

Comment: Do `null` parameter values make sense? Usually a missing key is treated as "Parameter not specified". There are too many question marks (optionals) anyway.

Comment: What library/API are you using to call the API and convert the dictionary to JSON? Surely you can just pass the dictionary containing the `NSNull`s to it and it should be able to understand that and convert that to JSON `null`s, right? You shouldn't need this conversion.

Comment: @Sweeper I am using SwiftyJSON. Yes you are correct it will understand directly passing dictionary,  when I did not entry any thing in fields its take empty String, when string is empty it should take null as params. as said vadian do null parameters.  for empty strings response message different for null response message different getting from api.

Comment: @kiran you can paste the json here: https://app.quicktype.io and it will give you the corresponding code. No need for 3rd party libraries.

Comment: @koen here is the json {"is_Valid”:false,”name”:null,”place”:null,”date”:null,”notes”:null}

Answer (score 0):

This is just the code generated by [app.quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io) based on your example json:

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - Test
struct Test: Codable {
    let isValid: Bool
    let name, place, date, notes: JSONNull?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case isValid = "is_Valid"
        case name, place, date, notes
    }
}

// MARK: - Encode/decode helpers

class JSONNull: Codable, Hashable {

    public static func == (lhs: JSONNull, rhs: JSONNull) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    public var hashValue: Int {
        return 0
    }

    public init() {}

    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if !container.decodeNil() {
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(JSONNull.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for JSONNull"))
        }
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encodeNil()
    }
}

let input = """
{
    "is_Valid": false,
    "name": null,
    "place": null,
    "date": null,
    "notes": null
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let test = try JSONDecoder().decode(Test.self, from: input)
print(test)
```

Output:

`Test(isValid: false, name: nil, place: nil, date: nil, notes: nil)`